# Counting Consecutive Odd Variations

Tags: java, algorithm

I am currently trying to find the number of times a **target** number can be represented as the sum of two or more consecutive odd integers. I have code that finds the longest sequence of consecutive odds here:

```
public class consecutiveOdd {

static int target = 1000000;

public static void main(String[] args){

    int longestVariation = -1;

    int totalVariations = 0;

    for (int k = 1;; k++) {
        int i = target / k - k + 1;
        if (i <= 0) {
            break;
        }
        // Check if calculated i, can be the start of 'odd' sequence.
        if (target % k == 0 && i % 2 == 1) {
            longestVariation = k;
            totalVariations += 1;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(longestVariation); 
    System.out.println(totalVariations);

}

}
```

Although I am not sure it determines the correct **amount** of variations. Is there something I am overlooking?

Best,
Otterman

Comment: To me, it looks right. Do you have a reason to think it's not right?

Comment: If I run it on a target of 45 i get three variations. But I believe there is only 2. (5 + 7 + 9 + 11 + 13) & (13 + 15 + 17). Maybe It is only an off by one?

Comment: It's counting 45 = 45. If you don't want that you just need to start with `k == 2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer but it reminds me of Piaget's conservation tests:

```
23^2 - 22^2
☯☯☯☯☯☯☯☯☯☯☯☯☯☯☯☯☯☯☯☯☯☯☯
☯
☯
☯
☯
☯
☯
☯
☯
☯
☯
☯
☯
☯
☯
☯
☯
☯
☯
☯
☯
☯
☯
```

Which drawing has more marbles?

```
7^2 -  (6^2 + 6^2-5^2 + 5^2-4^2 + 4^2-3^2 + 3^2)  - 2^2
☯☯☯☯☯☯☯
☯☯☯☯☯☯☯
☯☯☯☯☯☯☯
☯☯☯☯☯☯☯
☯☯☯☯☯☯☯
☯☯☯☯☯
☯☯☯☯☯


9^2 -  (8^2 + 8^2-7^2 + 7^2)  - 6^2
☯☯☯☯☯☯☯☯☯
☯☯☯☯☯☯☯☯☯
☯☯☯☯☯☯☯☯☯
☯☯☯
☯☯☯
☯☯☯
☯☯☯
☯☯☯
☯☯☯
```

By the way, the longest consecutive odd partition of any perfect square always starts with `1`, which, in our drawing method, could be thought of as `(x² - 0²)`:

```
 4 = 1 + 3
 9 = 1 + 3 + 5
16 = 1 + 3 + 5 + 7
...etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

To be absolutely sure that your code is fine you can implement diffent solution for which you know that it yields the correct answer and compare it with your efficient method. You can do something like this:

```
public class ConsecutiveOdd {

    static String fast(int target) {

        int longestVariation = -1;

        int totalVariations = 0;

        for (int k = 1;; k++) {
            int i = target / k - k + 1;
            if (i <= 0) {
                break;
            }

            if (target % k == 0 && i % 2 == 1) {
                longestVariation = k;
                totalVariations += 1;
            }
        }

        return Integer.toString(longestVariation) + " " + Integer.toString(totalVariations);
    }

    static String slow(int target) {
        int longest_length  = -1;
        int total = 0;
        for (int start = 1; start <= target; start += 2) {
            int sum = 0;
            int t = start;
            int seq_length = 0;
            while (sum < target) {
                sum += t;
                seq_length++;
                t += 2;
            }
            if (sum == target) {
//                System.out.println(start);
//                System.out.println(seq_length);
                if (seq_length > longest_length)
                    longest_length = seq_length;
                total++;
            }
        }
        return Integer.toString(longest_length) + " " + Integer.toString(total);
    }


    static void test(int n) {
        int correct = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            if (!slow(i).equals(fast(i))) {
                System.out.printf("Testcase %d: FAIL\n", i);
            } else {
                System.out.printf("Testcase %d: OK\n", i);
                correct++;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("%d/%d\n", correct, n);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        test(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: @vish4071 why do you think so?

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't see you initialize `t` at the beginning in every loop. If you say, I'll delete my comments.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, your formula will produce the correct amount of variations. All consecutive sequences `s` of odd naturals are of the form `j * k + 2 * p`, where `p` is a pyramid number, `1 + 2 + 3...+ (k - 1)`, representing how many `2`'s we need to add to `j` to produce the next number in the sequence.

Since in your formula, `k` must divide `target` with no remainer, we get `k` `i`'s, where each `i` equals `target / k - (k - 1)`. Your formula also stipulates that `i` is odd. How many `2`'s would we need to add to `k` `i`'s to get `target`?

```
i = target / k - (k - 1)
multiply both sides by k
k * i = k * target / k - (k - 1) * k
k * i + (k - 1) * k = target
```

We would need to add `(k - 1) * k / 2` `2`'s to `k` `i`'s to get `target`. Looking back at our formula for the consecutive odd sequence, we see that that is fulfilled:

```
target = k * i + (k - 1) * k 
       = k * i + 2 * (k - 1) * k / 2
       = k * i + 2 * p  where p is the pyramid number (k - 1) * k / 2
```

Since your loop tries all possible `i`'s, we are guaranteed to pass by all possible consecutive odd sequences that sum to `target`.